# How to create a google map in jupyter notebook using Latitude and Longitude

Tags: python-2.7, api, pandas, google-maps, jupyter-notebook

```
    import gmaps
    import gmaps.datasets
    gmaps.configure(api_key="AI...") # Your Google API key

    locations = gmaps.datasets.load_dataset("starbucks_uk")

   fig = gmaps.Map()
    starbucks_layer = gmaps.symbol_layer(
        locations, fill_color="green", stroke_color="green", scale=2)
    fig.add_layer(starbucks_layer)
    fig
```

I am currently trying to load this in my jupyter notebook, however the map will not display

Any help on this would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you have the gmaps Juypter extension installed and activated? `jupyter nbextension enable --py --sys-prefix gmaps`. More [info](https://github.com/pbugnion/gmaps#installation).

Comment: @JanTrienes How do I do that.
Do i put 
     $ pip install gmaps in a command line or do I put that in the jupyter terminal?

Comment: Try executing the command on your command line, restart your notebook and try again. You need to have gmaps installed for this to work. One way is `pip install gmaps` on your shell.

Comment: @JanTrienes to install gmaps would I put that code in the jupyter terminal?

Comment: You would execute that command on the command line of your machine.

Comment: @JanTrienes Thank you. I have another question and was wondering if you would be able to help with it. I want to import my own data frame as I have longitude and latitude of places in 2 columns how would I load this in as it isnt a gmaps.dataset.load_dataset?

Comment: You would load a dataframe using [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html)

Answer (score 3):

first, You need to write this code in your terminal:

```
jupyter nbextension enable --py gmaps
```

and then make sure in your terminal you get "validating ok" in your terminal.

for the datasets itself, you need to write 'starbucks_kfc_uk' not "starbucks_uk"

next code should be like this:

```
starbucks_df = df[df['chain_name'] == 'starbucks']
starbucks_df = starbucks_df[['latitude', 'longitude']]

starbucks_layer = gmaps.symbol_layer(
    starbucks_df, fill_color="green", stroke_color="green", scale=2
)
fig = gmaps.figure()
fig.add_layer(starbucks_layer)
fig
```

And this is my result:

[image]